# Fail to implement region specification in NDSolve - Misreading the doc?

Tags: differential-equations, documentation

Potentially simple, but I fail to implement it. Consider the following example:

```
solOsc = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -x[t], x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 2}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[x[t] /. First@solOsc, {t, 0, 10}]
```

which produces the expected result of a harmonic oscillator. Obviously the solution is purely real, so I thought I could also use this functionality from the `NDSolve` documentation

```
NDSolve[eqns,u,{t,Subscript[t, min],Subscript[t, max]},{x,y}\[Element]\[CapitalOmega]]
```

to restrict `x` to be real-valued from the beginning. However,

```
solOsc2 = NDSolve[{x''[t] == -x[t], x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 2}, x, {t, 0, 10}, x \[Element] Reals];
```

produces a bunch of `NDSolve::femnr: "x\[Element]Reals is not a valid region specification. "`. So the question is: Am I misreading the doc - in the sense that the region specification is not meant for this purpose - or am I doing a stupid mistake with implementation?

As background: I am solving a big system of coupled equations and try to simplify things. However, for some reason solutions that should definitely be only real-valued tend to get a small imaginary part $\mathcal{O}\left(10^{-5}\right)$. I want to avoid this by restricting the affected variables to be real only.

**Edit**
Of course, if the functionality is not meant for the purpose I want to use it for: is there any possibility to enforce a real-valued solution?

**Edit 2**
So this is in principle the type of equation I am solving (not illustrating the issue because I am unable to find a simple situation to reproduce it - but it might help nevertheless):

```
mat = {{1, I*Sin[t]}, {-I*Sin[t], 3}};
fun[t_] = Table[r[i, j][t], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
var = Flatten@Table[r[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{fun'[t] == -I*(mat.fun[t] - fun[t].mat), fun[0] == DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}]}, var, {t, 0, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 20, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];
```

This is a master equation, where `mat` is hermitian and also `fun` will be hermitian, so its diagonal is purely real. However, I am sometimes facing imaginary elements on the order of `0.0001` on the diagonal although they should not appear according to the precision settings (as far as I understood). Therefore, I want to restrict `r[1,1]` and `r[2,2]`in this example explicitely to be real. Possible?

Comment: No, it is not meant for that purpose -- regions can be used only in independent variable specifications, and `Reals` is not a region (see `RegionQ`).

Comment: @ilian Okay, thanks for this. Do you or anyone else know if it is actually possible to enforce a real-only solution?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual problem. In general, there can be small imaginary parts due to numerical error, but the returned solution should still satisfy the system up to the precision and accuracy goals. Try using a higher `WorkingPrecision`, and you could apply `Re` after the solution is computed.

Comment: @ilian I have added a code snippet that illustrates the general way of solving my type of problem - however not showing the actual issue with left-over imaginary parts. I doubt it has to do with `WorkingPrecision` or so (the parameters I use are also given in the 2nd edit).

Comment: I wonder if you could call the imaginary part of the diagonal an invariant of the system and use [NDSolve's projection method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html)? As a side note, I was able to generate solutions with unwanted imaginary parts by setting working precision to 5.

Comment: @Ian i will check this projection method and also what exactly is meant by the invariant - maybe it works out (on the first glance, I'd say it should). Many thanks for the hint, didn't know about it.